# Excel: Display the value selected in a dropdown in a different cell

Tags: excel, list, drop-down-menu, reference, excel-formula

I have a drop down list (a filter) displaying area codes, when a code is selected the corresponding areas are shown below as expected. What I want to do is display the area code selected in a different cell, so cell C3 contains the drop down "Area" (which has been made using a filter), and then when a value is selected the cells below show the records for that area, but what I want is to display the value selected in "Area" in a different cell. This means that there will be the "Area" cell with the drop down, the records below that match that area, and another cell that shows the value(s) selected.

Is there a way of doing this?

For example, if the rows below the headers have the areas 03, 04, and 05, the filter in C3 contains a filter so that only rows with the area code 05 are shown, but what I want to do is get it so that when the filter is applied (so 05 is selected) the rows with the area 05 are shown, and the value 05 is shown in a different cell.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understood correctly, if you enter in cell d5: =c3
then d5 will repeat whatever was selected in the dropdown cell C3.

Comment: Yes, basically that is correct, I want another cell to display the value selected in the drop down menu

Comment: So, did you try what I suggested?

Comment: Simple and works like a charm, Ben Smith mark this as a correct answer please.